# Is this enough to tackle script / malicious code insertion in GET, POST requests?

Tags: php, xss, sql-injection

I've got legacy PHP code which attempts to prevent script/SQL injection with the following:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    reset($_POST);
    while (list($k,$v)=each($_POST)) {
        if(!is_array($_POST{$k}))
        {
            $val=str_replace("&amp;","&",htmlentities($v,ENT_QUOTES));
            $$k=$val;
            //$_POST{$k}=$val;

            if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            $_POST{$k}=$val;
            else
            $_POST{$k}=stripslashes($val);

        }
    }
}
```

The same is exactly replicated for $_GET as well.

Is this enough to prevent script/SQL injection?

Answer (score 7):

No. It's blacklist-based, it tries to take care of specific tricks involving html entities.  It doesn't even require magic_quotes, and magic_quotes has been deprecated as inadequate.  Chris Shiflett is just one of many who've written a [blog post](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) explaining how vulnerable that is; it won't even stop modern automated script-kiddie attacks.

Use prepared statements in the database, and you'll be most of the way there--although even prepared statements aren't foolproof.